# Remove everything before http in every element of array

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace, strstr

I got an array call `$urls`and i want to remove everything before `http` for every element in the  array

suppose

```
$urls[1] = hd720\u0026url=http%3A%2F%2Fr2---sn-h50gpup0nuxaxjvh-hg0l.googlevideo.com%2Fvideoplayback%3Fexpire%3D1387559704%26fexp%3D937407%252C908540%252C941239%252C916623%252C909717%252C932295%252C936912%252C936910%252C923305%252C936913%252C907231%252C907240%252C921090%
```

I want it to be

```
$urls[1] = http%3A%2F%2Fr2---sn-h50gpup0nuxaxjvh-hg0l.googlevideo.com%2Fvideoplayback%3Fexpire%3D1387559704%26fexp%3D937407%252C908540%252C941239%252C916623%252C909717%252C932295%252C936912%252C936910%252C923305%252C936913%252C907231%252C907240%252C921090%
```

Here i gave example only for $urls[1] but i want to remove every characters till http is found for ALL element of array

I tried

```
$urls = strstr($urls, 'http');
$urls = preg_replace('.*(?=http://)', '', $urls);
```

Both didn't work

Comment: where do you get this input from? looks like it would be better to fix the data source than the data

Comment: [`array_walk`](http://php.net/array-walk)

Answer (score 3):

Use [`array_map()`](http://php.net/array_filter) with a callback function:

```
$urls = array_map(function($url) {
    return preg_replace('~.*(?=http://)~', '$1', urldecode($url));
}, $urls);
```

[**Demo.**](https://eval.in/81443)

Comment: @user2650277: Glad to have been of help :)

Answer (score 0):

[`strstr`](http://www.php.net/function.strstr) coupled with [`array_map`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php) gives you the expected result.

```
$furls = array_map('filterArr',$urls);
function filterArr($v)
{
return urldecode(strstr($v,'http'));
}
print_r($furls);
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd do it like this:

```
foreach($urls as $key=>$val) {
    $e = &$urls[$key]; // notice the &  sign
    // now whatever you do with $e will go back
    // into the original array element
    $e = preg_replace(.............);
}
```

I always use this technique to convert arrays since it's fast and efficient. The array_walk / array_filter way is also good but much slower when your array is medium to big.

Answer (score 0):

You can cut everything before http with explode.

```
       $string = explode("http", $urls);       // Hold the url and cut before the http
       $str = $string[0]; // Hold the first cut - E.G : hd720\u0026url=
       echo $str; // Hold the first cut - E.G : hd720\u0026url=
```

Also note that `$string[1];` will hold the other side of http : `%3A%2F%2Fr2---sn-h50...

So you can do it somthing like that :

```
   $str1 = $string[1];
   $fixedUrl =  'http'.$str1; // will hold the fixed http : http%3A%2F%2Fr2---sn-h50gpup0nuxaxjvh-hg0l...
```

Answer (score 0):

You just miss delimiters arround your regex, [preg_replace](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php) works well on array:

```
$urls = preg_replace('~.*(?=http://)~', '', $urls);
// add delimiters   __^           __^
```

I used `~` to avoid escaping the `//`, in this case, it'll be:

```
$urls = preg_replace('/.*(?=http:\/\/)/', '', $urls);
// add delimiters   __^             __^
```